# sphinx doesn't show any documentation (sphinx w/ plone)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx, plone, autodoc

i have 544 warnings like this . i try to dcument **python(plone)** code with **sphinx 1.8.5**

> qoute WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'lims.workflow.worksheet' from module u'bika'; the following exception was raised: No module named App

this my `conf.py`

```
import os
import sys
import sphinx_rtd_theme
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..'))

...

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    "sphinx.ext.autosummary", 
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
    'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
    'sphinx_rtd_theme',
]

...

exclude_patterns = [u'_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store', '**tests**', '**spi**']
```

And this my `index.rst`

```
Welcome to moh's documentation!
===============================
.. automodule:: bika
 

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   modules

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`


WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u* from module u*; the following exception was raised:
No module named *
```

This is where I am so far, the packages titles are visible but can't quite see what's inside them yet, how can I fix that?
[This is a screenshot from the docs and how they look so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWDU8.png)

and this is **tree**

```html
<pre>
├── bika
│   ├── doc3
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __init__.pyo
│   ├── lims
│   └── __pycache__
├── doc2
│   ├── bika.lims.adapters.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.api.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.analyses.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.analysisrequest.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.batch.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.bootstrap.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.chart.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.client.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.client.views.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.dashboard.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.department.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.fields.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.idserver.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.portlets.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.publish.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.reports.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.reports.selection_macros.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.resultsimport.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.viewlets.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.widgets.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.workflow.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.worksheet.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.browser.worksheet.views.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.catalog.indexers.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.catalog.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.content.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.controlpanel.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.events.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.genericsetup.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.abaxis.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.abaxis.vetscan.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.abbott.m2000rt.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.abbott.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.alere.pima.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.alere.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.beckmancoulter.access.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.beckmancoulter.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.biodrop.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.biodrop.ulite.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.cobasintegra.model_400_plus.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.cobasintegra.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.eltra.cs.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.eltra.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.facscalibur.calibur.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.facscalibur.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.foss.fiastar.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.foss.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.foss.winescan.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.generic.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.genexpert.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.horiba.jobinyvon.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.horiba.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.lachat.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.lifetechnologies.qubit.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.lifetechnologies.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.metler.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.metler.toledo.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.myself.myinstrument.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.myself.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.nuclisens.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.panalytical.omnia.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.panalytical.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.rigaku.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.rigaku.supermini.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.rochecobas.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.rochecobas.taqman.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.scilvet.abc.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.scilvet.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.sealanalytical.aq2.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.sealanalytical.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.shimadzu.gcms.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.shimadzu.icpe.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.shimadzu.nexera.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.shimadzu.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.sysmex.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.sysmex.xs.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.sysmex.xt.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.tescan.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.tescan.tima.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.thermoscientific.arena.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.thermoscientific.gallery.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.thermoscientific.multiskan.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.thermoscientific.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.varian.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.instruments.varian.vistapro.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.exportimport.setupdata.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.install.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.interfaces.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.jsonapi.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.locales.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.monkey.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.subscribers.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.tests.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.upgrade.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.utils.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.vocabularies.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.workflow.analysisrequest.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.workflow.analysis.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.workflow.analysisservice.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.workflow.duplicateanalysis.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.workflow.instrument.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.workflow.referenceanalysis.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.workflow.rst
│   ├── bika.lims.workflow.worksheet.rst
│   ├── bika.rst
│   ├── _build
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── modules.rst
│   ├── _static
│   └── _templates
├── EGG-INFO
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── entry_points.txt
│   ├── namespace_packages.txt
│   ├── not-zip-safe
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
└── node_modules
    ├── inherits
    ├── opentype.js
    ├── pako
    ├── pdfjs
    ├── pdf-merger-js
    ├── readable-stream
    ├── @rkusa
    ├── safe-buffer
    ├── string_decoder
    ├── string.prototype.codepointat
    ├── tiny-inflate
    ├── unicode-trie
    ├── unorm
    ├── util-deprecate
    └── uuid
<pre>
```

**project files in bika >> lims **

Comment: The warning provides a hint. Somewhere in your package, you try to import `u*`.